# Change browser tab title to file name when send_file pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, browser, metadata, carrierwave

In my project I'm using *Carrierwave* to upload files like doc, and **pdf**.
In case I want to download a **pdf** my controller do

> *send_file* **@document**, :*disposition* =>
>   'inline', :*type* => **'application/pdf'**

And this works fine, displays the pdf file in browser and the url I get is **/documents/file_name** and it's fine too. But I want to set the *"headers title"* or *"url title"* so in the browser's tab shows the **file_name** instead ***myapp.com/documents/file_name***

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is not possible as you describe.

The tab title is taken from the PDF documents metadata, specifically the Title attribute.

If you usually generate your document with Prawn you can do:

`Prawn::Document.generate(my_filename, info: {Title: my_title})`